# Is Hacker Hack Speed based on ATK %?

Tags: mechabellum

I've been playing a lot of Mechabellum lately and love the Hacker unit, but it's really hard to tell whether or not there's any way of improving their rate of Hacking other than just ranking them up. There's a lot of Reinforcements that can increase ATK%, so I thought about putting those on there to help, but in hindsight I wasn't sure if it actually improved their conversion rate.

**Do ATK% increases improve the conversion rate of Hackers?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's go to Solo...
[image: screenshot of Mechabellum's menu, with visible icon and options of "Multiplayer", "Solo", and cropped "Tourn" for "Tournament"]

...boot up Testing Grounds...
[image: screenshot of cropped bottom right corner of Solo menu, featuring big tile for Testing Grounds]

...place a lone Hacker...
[image: screenshot of lvl1 Hacker's stat plate, with ATK value of 585 highlighted]

...pick a Senior Attack Specialist...
[image: screenshot of Senior Attack Sepcialist tile and tooltip that says "Increases the attack of all units by 30%"]

...check the Hacker again...
[image: screenshot of lvl1 Hacker's stat plate, with the increased ATK value of 760 highlighted]

...and *bada-bing, bada-boom*, we have the answer:

## yes, Hacker's hacking speed is based on ATK